# Can we add formula (tool) in brew list?

Tags: macos, homebrew

According to brew document(https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage) we can install tools which Apple didn’t include with macOS.
Can we add our custom (third party) tool in brew list (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/) and if yes then what is procedure for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules limit what is an [acceptable formula](https://docs.brew.sh/Acceptable-Formulae) so having your own tool accepted would seem to depend on its popularity.

> **Niche (or self-submitted) stuff**
>
> The software in question must:
>
> - be maintained (i.e. the last release wasn’t ages ago, it works
>     without patching on all supported macOS releases and has no
>     outstanding, unpatched security vulnerabilities)
> - be known
> - be stable (e.g. not declared “unstable” or “beta” by upstream)
> - be used
> - have a homepage
>
> We will reject formulae that seem too obscure, partly because they won’t get maintained and partly because we have to draw the line somewhere.
>
> We frown on authors submitting their own work unless it is very popular.

You can however create your own tap containing whatever you want. See [How to create and maintain a tap](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap)

> Taps are external sources of Homebrew formulae and/or external commands. They can be created by anyone to provide their own formulae and/or external commands to any Homebrew user.